# React Context provider doesn't send the data

Tags: reactjs

So I want to pass totalAmount which is a useState from Restaurant.js to Header.js using context in AuthContext.js. Header.js can receive value from AuthContext.js but Restaurant.js can't pass data to AuthContext.js

**Restaurant.js**
This is the provider. Sending totalAmount which is a hook useState

```
import React, { useState, useReducer, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import DaftarMenu from './components/Menu/DaftarMenu';
import AuthContext from './components/Context/AuthContext';

const orderReducer = (state,action) =>{ 
 if (action.type==='AMOUNT_INPUT'){
   return {amount: state.amount+parseInt(action.val)};
  }
};

const Restaurant = () => {
const menu = [
  {  
     id: 'e1',
     name: 'Sushi',
     description: 'Finest fish and veggies',
     price: 22.99,
     amount: 0
   },
   {
     id: 'e2',
     name: 'Schnitzel',
     description: 'A German specialty!',
     price: 16.50,
     amount: 0
   },
   {
     id: 'e3',
     name: 'Barbecue Burger',
     description: 'American, raw, meaty',
     price: 12.99,
     amount: 0
   },
   { 
     id: 'e4',
     name: 'Green Bowl',
     description: 'Healthy and green',
     price: 18.99,
     amount: 0
   }
];
 const [daftarMenu, setDaftarMenu] = useState(menu);
 const [inputAmount, setInputAmount] = useState(0);
 const [inputName, setInputName] = useState('');
 const [totalAmount, setTotalAmount] = useState(0);
 const [state,dispatch] = useReducer(orderReducer,{name:'', amount:0});

   useEffect(() => {
    onChangeMenu(inputName);
     },[state.amount]);

   useEffect(() => {
    console.log(daftarMenu);
    console.log(totalAmount);
     },[daftarMenu, totalAmount]);

 const onSaveAmountInput = (event) => { 
  dispatch({type:'AMOUNT_INPUT', val:event});
  setInputAmount(event);
 };

 const onSaveNameInput = (event) => { 
  setInputName(event);
 };

 const onChangeMenu = (name) => { 

 setTotalAmount(totalAmount + parseInt(inputAmount));
 const updatedMenu = daftarMenu.map(obj => {
     if (obj.name === name) {
        return {...obj, amount: obj.amount + parseInt(inputAmount)};
     }
     return obj;
   });
  
  setDaftarMenu(updatedMenu);
 };




   return(

    <AuthContext.Provider
     value={{
       totalAmount:totalAmount,
     }}
   >
        <DaftarMenu items={daftarMenu} amountInput={onSaveAmountInput} nameInput={onSaveNameInput} />
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default Restaurant;
```

**AuthContext.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const AuthContext = React.createContext({
  totalAmount: 0
});

export default AuthContext;
```

**Header.js**

This is the consumer. Right now I just want to console.log the data received from the provider

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import AuthContext from '../Context/AuthContext';

const Header = () => {
     const ctx = useContext(AuthContext);
     console.log(ctx.totalAmount);
  return (
    <p>  </p>
);
  };
export default Header;
```

console.log in Header.js results in 0.

Comment: Are you sure that `onMenuChange` runs first?

Comment: Actually yes. Does it have anything to do with the context api?

Comment: This is the only place that you change the `totalAmount`, but I'm not sure if you set it to something else than `0`

Comment: In Restaurant.js, I have tried sending other values other than totalAmount. But it didn't seem reach the AuthContext.js

Comment: Could you create an example on codesandbox?

Comment: here https://codesandbox.io/s/green-fog-t9m0x3?file=/src/index.js

Comment: `Header` is not inside the context provider

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property when using React context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73502719/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-destructure-property-when-using-react-context)